# SetTimeout does not work correctly in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[This is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/EmadHelmi/mbfw25ak/).
I want the images get larger after one second if I hold the mouse on each of them but there is no response from the `setTimeout`. Even when I put an `alert()` function at the beginning of the `menuChanging()` function, it runs but the rest of my code does not execute (it runs immediately, not after one second).

Comment: need to share the code in question

Comment: i try to do this but i couldnt

Answer (score 5):

You are invoking the function `menuChanging` immediately on mouseover, instead you need to pass a function reference to setTimeout

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hormenu > div").hover(function() {
    $(this).data('hoverTimer', setTimeout(menuChanging.bind(this), 1000));
  }, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    //if you move out before 1s then clear the timer
    clearTimeout($this.data('hoverTimer'));

    //when the mouse is moved out restore to initial state if required
    if ($this.hasClass('current')) {
      $this.toggleClass("current other").animate({
        width: "100px",
        opacity: "0.5"
      }, 750, 'easeOutBounce');
    }
  });
});

function menuChanging() {
  var duration = 750;
  $(".hormenu > .current").not(this).toggleClass("current other").animate({
    width: "100px",
    opacity: "0.5"
  }, duration, 'easeOutBounce');
  $(this).removeClass("other").addClass("current").animate({
    width: "600px",
    opacity: "1"
  }, duration, 'easeOutBounce');
}
```

```css
.hormenu {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1800px;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.hormenu div {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
.other {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
img {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="hormenu">
  <div class="current">
    <img src="http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/b844e6ef0e3320bc945a9b5b1cd196f9_large.jpeg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    <img src="http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/20c41d877dfbed0e52947f51846df781_large.jpeg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    <img src="http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/b844e6ef0e3320bc945a9b5b1cd196f9_large.jpeg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what should i write instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a solution to your issue.

```
$(function(){
    $(".hormenu div").mouseover(
        function()
        {
            setTimeout(menuChanging($(this)),1000);
        }
        );
});

function menuChanging(div) {
    return function(){
        var duration = 750 ;
        if (!div.hasClass("current")) {
            $(".current").removeClass("current").addClass("other").animate({
                width: "100px",
                opacity: "0.5"
            }, duration, 'easeOutBounce');
        }
        div.removeClass("other").addClass("current").animate({
            width: "600px",
            opacity: "1"
        }, duration, 'easeOutBounce');
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mbfw25ak/3/)

You were calling the function and not passing it to setTimeout. I also changed some things to retrieve easily the div. The new function returns a function to call and this new function can access the first one's parameter.